# Algorithm: How to smoothly interpolate/reconstruct sparse samples with noise?

Tags: algorithm, interpolation, approximation

This question is not directly related to a particular programming language but is an algorithmic question.

What I have is a lot of samples of a 2D function. The samples are at random locations, they are not uniformly distributed over the domain, the sample values contain noise and each sample has a confidence-weight assigned to it.

What I'm looking for is an algorithm to reconstruct the original 2D function based on the samples, so a function `y' = G(x0, x1)` that approximates the original well and interpolates areas where samples are sparse smoothly.

It goes into the direction of what [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) is doing, but with the added difficulty that:

- the sample values contain noise - meaning that samples should not just be interpolated, but nearby samples also averaged in some way to average out the sampling noise.
- the samples are weighted, so, samples with higher weight should contrbute more strongly to the reconstruction that those with lower weight.

scipy.interpolate.griddata seems to do a Delaunay triangulation and then use the barycentric cordinates of the triangles to interpolate values. This doesn't seem to be compatible with my requirement of weighting samples and averaging noise though.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like curve-fitting and regression, not interpolation.  What is the shape of your original function?  Is it y = mx + b?

Comment: no, it's an arbitrary function on a 2D surface. It's actually defined on a sphere but for simplicity I first want to understand the 2D carthesian case

Comment: @user1282931 Actually the sphere is the simpler case!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, the function is defined on a sphere.  That simplifies life because your region is both well-studied and nicely bounded!

First, decide how many [Spherical Harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) you will use in your approximation.  The fewer you use, the more you smooth out noise.  The more you use, the more accurate it will be.  But if you use any of a particular degree, you should use all of them.

And now you just impose the condition that the sum of the squares of the weighted errors should be minimized.  That will lead to a system of linear equations, which you then solve to get the coefficients of each harmonic function.

Comment: that was actually my approach so far, but that doesn't work well for two reasons: first, since there is (monte carlo) noise in the samples, minimizing the sum of squares actually amplifies noise because samples farther away from the average i'm looking for get weighted more. Secondly, the areas where there are no samples don't get interpolated smoothly, the SH values go quite crazy there (probably a similar problem like ringing). So I thought I first want to create a uniform resampling and average the noise before transforming to SH